# Home Network Bandwidth Control

Tags: home-networking, network-shares, bandwidth, adsl

I will mount a home network to share the ADSL internet connection. The speed is 1Mb, but I want that my PC get 75% of the bandwidth and the another PC get 25%.

I know that linux boxes can do it, but then I will need an extra PC, because all PCs are WinXP .

What solutions I can do use (free is better)?

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your router doesn't support traffic shaping, you can install this on each computer:

> **[Traffic Shaper XP](http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html)** is a free bandwidth limiter for Windows 2000, XP
>   and 2003 Server. It combines high
>   performance traffic shaping with the
>   ease of use and flexibility to keep
>   your network free of congestion.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [QoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_Service), assuming your router/gateway supports it.  This should also be on Superuser.

Answer (score 1):

As churnd mentioned, router gateway support of QOS is what you are looking for.  If you are using certain Linksys, Buffalo, or Asus hardware, and are comfortable applying a third-party firmware to your device, you can replace the standard firmware with [Tomato](http://polarcloud.com) and get really good QOS control with live graphs that show how your traffic is being prioritized.  It allows you to prioritize by physical port, network port and protocol.  More information about supported hardware can be found [here](http://polarcloud.com/tomatofaq#what_will_this_run_on).