# How can I set different bandwith for different PC in my LAN

Tags: internet, wireless-networking, lan, bandwidth, internet-connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Customize LAN to favor bandwidth to one computer](https://superuser.com/questions/86696/customize-lan-to-favor-bandwidth-to-one-computer)

I have a LAN ( with 2 computers: a laptop and a desktop computer ) I want more bandwidth allocated to my laptop, for downloads. Is it possible ?

Comment: I want a bandwitch. It sounds tasty. ;) How about some bandwidth instead?

Answer (score 1):

A router with QoS will allow you to allocate bandwidth between the different nodes on your LAN.

Answer (score 0):

For a software solution, try **[NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com)** - free trial, $19.95 for Lite version with limits. Install on your desktop to limit its download speed.