# How can I reduce bandwidth of a computer in LAN?

Tags: windows, internet, lan, bandwidth, connection-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Home Network Bandwidth Control](https://superuser.com/questions/79838/home-network-bandwidth-control)

The title might be confusing as I don't know the correct terminology.

The situation is:

I have two PCs connected directly to each other. One of the PC connects directly to internet and the other shares this internet connection. I want to lower the priority of requests from the second PC i.e. I want to reduce the internet bandwidth for the other PC.

I want to restrict the internet usage of the other PC by providing it less bandwidth.

Is it possible? If Yes, How?

PS: Both system has Windows XP SP2.

Comment: What switch do you use? Router? Firewall?

Comment: Are you using microsoft's Internet Connection Sharing?

Comment: Not related to your question... But may I suggest you upgrade to Windows XP Service Pack 3...

Comment: @Chris_K: Yes, I'm using microsoft's Internet Connection Sharing...

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is called quality of service.
imo you have two possibilities:

1. when you are using firefox, you could use [this](http://www.uselessapplications.com/en/Application/FirefoxThrottle.aspx) ff plugin.
2. you can use windows own qos. here are some links to informations from microsoft:
   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316666
   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.02.cableguy.aspx

Answer (score 1):

QoS, like others have stated is probably your best option.

One thing you need to keep in mind, there is a difference between lowering the bandwidth output, and lowering the priority of network/internet based traffic.

When you lower the bandwidth, you reduce the amount of information that can be transmitted within a certain amount of time.

When you lower the priority, it determines if there is any higher priority data being transmitted (or in the queue) and if so, adds itself to the end of the queue where it is lower then the others. Your actual bandwidth used in a certain amount of time, remains the same.

So, you should probably consider this and refine your question.

Are you trying to lower consumption/bandwidth in a certain amount of time, or reduce the priority of the second computer's traffic?

Comment: +1 Thanks for making me understand the correct terminologies...I want to lower consumption of internet on the second PC...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind installing something on the second PC, check out [Traffic Shaper XP](http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html):

[image]

Traffic Shaper XP is freeware.