# What are the ways to monitor and limit the internet connection speed that individual computers are getting from my wireless router?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reduce bandwidth of a computer in LAN?](https://superuser.com/questions/95491/how-can-i-reduce-bandwidth-of-a-computer-in-lan)

My neighbors are planning to connect to the internet through my home wi-fi hence I will have to give them the WPA/WPA2 key. But I want to limit their bandwidth so they won't eat it all up.

I am using Buffalo WHR-G125.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to do it in the router software, not all routers have this ability, most people choose a linksys model that can run DD-WRT firmware (software)

http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index

Looks like your model supports DD-WRT, do plenty of reading before attempting to flash the firmware on your router, doing it incorrectly or using the wrong firmware can render your router useless.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices#Buffalo

Check the software already in your router, it may have the features you need already, consult the owners manual on how to view router settings.