# How to get more bandwidth for my laptop than desktop in my home network

Tags: laptop, wireless-router, internet-connection, bandwidth, desktop-computer

In my home network we have desktop with wired Internet connection and laptop with wireless Internet connection. So I want more bandwidth for my laptop than desktop, both are on same Internet connection

Comment: what ever action i want to do, i have to do on my laptop only and i dont want to touch the desktop

Comment: If you are connected using a 802.11N network device to a 802.11N router then you won't be able to get "any" faster at least not until 802.11/ac

Comment: So, you're asking to improve the speed of the laptop without 'downgrading' the speed of the desktop? Well, what is your network speed capable of on laptop and router? Remember, the speeds are always only as fast as the slowest connection/point on the network.

Comment: hi dave thanks for your reply. i want to downgrade the desktop speed and i want to improve the laptop speed

Comment: hmmm.. out of my depth a little buy maybe QoS (quality of service) from your router may help but you may need specialist equipment. Are they both constantly in use at the same time? If not, then actually you don't need to worry about the desktop speed.

Comment: yes both are working parallel, that time i want to get more speed

Comment: Bandwith != speed

Comment: how come joe, can you explain in brief?

Comment: @subbarao can't or do not want to touch the desktop? That is where you need to do the throttling.. otherwise you need access to the router/switch. Please supply the model

Comment: @ Dennis - Sorry, lost track of the rules etc and not sure if I did at the time of the post?!           
@ Subbarao - do you have a router that supports QoS (although it looks like Cadburry has also now commented on this)

Comment: [Home Network Bandwidth Control](http://superuser.com/q/79838)

Comment: To elaborate on Joe's comment (and I wish i could +5 it) bandwidth is a pipeline, like a freeway, it does not actually control how fast the cars go, it just dictates how many can fit on it at one time, and when the highway gets clogged, the slower the cars move. Speed is latency, how fast the packets can physically move along the pipeline, like the speed limit of a highway, but is affected by various factors (ability of switches to move packets, number of switches, physical distance between end points, etc).

Comment: @subbarao Why are you unable to access the desktop?  Is this something a parent put in place to restrict speed?  If so, we won't help.  Also, this may seem like an emergency to you, but to us, this is something we will need time to understand your situation before we can possibly start helping.

Answer (score 2):

if your router supports QOS (quality of service) you can prefer one device by its MAC address

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if both are working in parallel then i want to increase more bandwidth to my laptop

Comment: i need the answer please

Comment: i dont know your enviroment,
1: does your router support QOS?
2: do you mean bandwith to the internet or in your LAN environment
3: are both computers connected over LAN or is your Notebook Connected via W-LAN?

Comment: @subbarao - Give your laptop a higher QOS value then your desktop.  Please don't spam "for an answer" really annoying.

Comment: Router QoS settings work only up to your router. This will not work on the rest of your connection. This means that traffic from your router to your machines will be prioritized, but not on your ISP's circuit. You may query google at the same time with both computers and your router will prioritize the laptop and push all the packets out to the circuit first, but once there, your laptop's packets may take a back seat through your ISP's ATM cloud and onward and your desktop may still receive a response first.

Comment: @Rahmound- if i got the answer no need to post any comment

Comment: subbarao: - i'm sorry - but you wont get a full answer until you answer our questions in the comments... your task could be very complex in its configuration, so we cant go on without your answer!
@MaQleod - ur right thats why i'm asking (2)